# How do I remove an unstoppable pipeline job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the [Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) (formerly Workflow) plugin collection for Jenkins. I've somehow managed to create a workflow job on my Jenkins server that I cannot stop. Querying the current stack traces with `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().each() {  t -> println(t.getName())}` does not return any executors in the output matching this job. On top of that, if this is the only live job in the Build Executor Status window, there are no executors listed at all.

Restarting the slave that the job was executing on had no effect. Restarting the Jenkins master server had no effect either. Any thoughts on how I could get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to stop the job by submitting a POST request to:
`http://jenkins.fqdn:8080/job/$JobName/branch/$BranchName/8/term` (Note the $JobName and $BranchName variables)

I found this URI by doing the following:

1. Click on the number next to the job to navigate to that exact job.
2. Click the Console Output link.
3. Right-Click the "Click here to forcibly terminate running steps" link.
4. Click the Inspect menu item. (This is in Chrome; adjust this step for your preferred browser)
5. Copy the URI from inside the Ajax.Request call. E.g.:`onclick="new Ajax.Request('`**`http://jenkins.fqdn:8080/job/$JobName/branch/$BranchName/8/term`**`'); false"`

For some reason, clicking the `Click here to forcibly terminate running steps` link didn't actually terminate the job, but submitting a post request manually did. I suspect it's probably just a little bug in the UI code.

Comment: Accepting my own answer since there have been no other answers for a significant period of time.

Comment: Yes, difficult to find... wish there was a means to identify and kill these using groovy - we discovered 45 "old builds" in this state across a half dozen jobs.

Comment: Used postman to send a post request and it asked me to be authenticated, so I chose the Basic Auth with my credentials and it worked

Comment: @Sergey Pleshakov - please add you proposed edits as a new answer.

Answer (score 9):

I've got the same problem today and workaround from the comment above didn't help me as well as sending `/kill` command instead of `/term`.

I found [working solution here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/N5UOQr418o0/jiggOuIzBAAJ):

1. OPEN https://your.jenkins.fqdn/script
2. PUT `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("jobName").getBuildByNumber(9).finish(hudson.model.Result.ABORTED, new java.io.IOException("Aborting build"));`
3. PRESS "Run"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way that worked well for me many times. All you need to do is to edit `onclick` attribute in html page, by following

1. Open up a console log of the job (pipeline) that got hang
2. Click whatever is available to kill the job (x icon, "Click here to forcibly terminate running steps" etc) to get "Click here to forcibly kill entire build" link visible (it's **NOT** gonna be clickable at the moment)
3. Open the browser's console (*use any one of three for chrome: F12; ctrl + shift + i; menu->more tools->developer tools*)
4. Locate "Click here to forcibly kill entire build" link manually or using "select an element in the page" button of the console
5. Double click on `onclick` attribute to edit its value
6. Append `s` to `http` to have `https`
7. Press enter to submit the changes
8. Click "Click here to forcibly kill entire build" link

Use screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: This is what @kivagant suggested above: using /kill after the build url.  Unfortunately - depending on how the build is behaving - the link you describe may get buried in a slew of trace messages or what-have-you. And be pages, and pages away from the end of the build console output.